# How can I enable/disable MySQL slow query logging on Amazon RDS without restarting

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I would like to enable/disable slow query logging on an Amazon RDS instance without having to restart. I'm aware that I can do this by changing the `slow_query_log` parameter in the instance's parameter group, but this requires me to restart.

On the other hand, I've seen that this is possible with `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';` in MySQL, but this requires super privileges, which are restricted to the `rdsadmin` user on Amazon RDS.

I've also found this resource: [How do I enable functions, procedures, and triggers for my Amazon RDS MySQL instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/) but the description says *"when binary logging is enabled"*, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 3):

The `slow_query_log` variable [is a dynamic variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log).

Dynamic variables can be updated [without a restart](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html):

> When you change a dynamic parameter and save the DB parameter group,
>   the change is applied immediately regardless of the Apply Immediately
>   setting.

So just change it and you should see the effects immediately.

Comment: Yes, I saw that it's a dynamic variable, but still, after I change it, the instance's state is `applying`, and then it's `pending-reboot` :/

Comment: Have slow queries started/stopped being logged? long_query_time (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) is also a dynamic variable. Set it to a very small number (or even 0) and it should log every single query. Slow logs are written and downloadable in real time, so you should be able to immediately see the effects. We've changed these variables at my work before without doing a reboot, so I know from experience it should work.

Comment: I just tried switching between parameter groups where the only difference is the slow query log setting. After applying, the instance status said "modifying", but the instance was still available during that time.

Answer (score 0):

This is all documented on the AWS documentation site, [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Generallog).

> You can monitor the MySQL error log, slow query log, and the general log. The MySQL error log is generated by default; you can generate the slow query and general logs by setting parameters in your DB parameter group.

Comment: Thanks, but the emphasis of the question was how to do it without having to restart the RDS instance. I want to be able to switch it on and off on production. Changing the parameter group, as you suggest, does require a restart in this case.

Comment: I should probably learn to read